# Created basic angular app using the cli. Want to get rid of mixed content warnings

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get rid of the mixed content warnings by setting all the font requests to https. I can't seem to find where the fonts are being requested though.

[image: Chrome Dev Console]

Comment: The default template doesn't have any references to fonts. You must have added something else.

Comment: That's actually part of the reason why I'm so puzzled. I followed the directions here to step 3: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html. I also deployed to firebase but I doubt that could have had an influence

Comment: It can be your extension injecting junks.

Comment: Ah! That's it. Thank you so much

Comment: I ran into this when using `https://dreamyguy.github.com/progrock-norway/` as `--base-href` when building. All warnings were gone once I used `https://dreamyguy.github.io/progrock-norway/` (note the **`io`**)